# Passive vs. permissive

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, word-choice

What is the difference between *passive* and *permissive*? They both seem to have the same meaning, in the sense that they both allow something to happen and not doing anything about it and if they are, which one is used more in everyday English?

*Example:*

> Jack you should do something about it or they are going to see you as a *passive/permissive* leader?

Comment: Have you consulted a good dictionary? That should always be your first step; if that leaves you puzzled, you can come tell us what the dictionary says and why you are still confused, and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: They are both correct, the word passive/permissive reflects the "leader" outlook and personality. Depending on the leader, the appropriate word can be chosen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between the two is that *passive* is used for someone who accepts or allows things to happen, without trying to change anything. Whereas *permissive*  is giving freedom to individuals to do things as they like when they like.

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/permissive) in a simple definition defines *permissive* as:

> giving people a lot of freedom or too much freedom to do what they want to do

And for *passive* the [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/passive) dictionary, in a simple definition defines it as:

> used to describe someone who allows things to happen or who accepts what other people do or decide without trying to change anything

Answer (score 0):

A 'permissive' person allows things to happen, but a 'passive' person allows things to happen **to himself**.